# React external script method is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to import [BlotterJS](https://blotter.js.org/) on my React projet so I set it in my index.html file as :

```
<script crossorigin src="https://rawgit.com/bradley/Blotter/master/build/blotter.min.js"></script>
```

I'm using it on my component: in `componentWillMount` I generate the Blotter text with my method `generateText` but it needs to create a new `Blotter` instance. Here is the component:

```
export class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.text = this.generateText()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div id="welcome"></div>
        <nav>
          <div className={styles.double_buttons}>
            <Link to="/about" className={`button ${styles.button_small}`}>About me</Link>
            <Link to="/work" className="button button_small">Work</Link>
          </div>
          <Link to="/contact" className="button button_large">Contact</Link>
        </nav>
      </div>
    )
  }
  generateText () {
    return new Blotter.Text("WELCOME.", {
      family : "'EB Garamond', serif",
      size : 50,
      fill : "#202020"
    })
  }
  // Things here to generate the material and create the scope, but same issue, I can't do this because it needs Blotter too
}
```

I'm getting the following error: [image: error]
I just want to be able to use the Blotter type. I don't know if I'm importing BlotterJS correctly.

Comment: Maybe don't fail your build on lint errors? That would let you experiment at least.

Comment: What are you using to build your project?

Comment: Without the linter it doesn't compile anymore, and I'm using Webpack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `window.Blotter` instead of `Blotter`.

It seems your compiler isn't finding the variable definition and throwing an error, but your logic seems fine so I would guess this will fix it.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using webpack then you need to configure Blotter as an external library. Refer webpack documentation:
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

Essentially, you can add following to your **webpack.config.js**

```
externals: {
    Blotter: 'Blotter'
}
```

After that you can use it as any other library:

```
import Blotter from 'Blotter';
```

Comment: Yes but you'll think it going to work even if Blotter is not an NPM package ?

Comment: That's exactly what externals are for. Created bundle relies on dependency to be present in the consumer's environment. Here <script/> tag will make it available for created bundle. I have used externals for google apis.